# Tracking wifes iphone and one minute it was 100kms for the original location

Tags: find-my-iphone

So i was was using find my iphone to track my wifes location. 
She was at her mothers place then the next minute she was 100kms away. 
Any ideas how that can happen?
Thanks

Comment: Does her mother live in a high-rise building?

Comment: yes she does . why?

Comment: In some cases, altitude seems to confuse the location algorithm.  If you are not a ground level, sometimes you appear to be kms away!

Comment: in fact I got the original questions upside down.

Comment: She is currently at the holiday house 100kms from her mothers. Last night occasionally when I first opened the app it would show her mothers location. Then I awake this morning and it shows her mothers location for the first hour then resorts back to the holiday house.

Comment: A car or aerial vehicle able to travel at 6000 kph could do the job. Access to a portal gun might also permit such rapid relocation.